# How to use make_password and check_password manually?

Tags: python, django

I try to use `make_password` and `check_password` functions manually. I do it like this in one of my views (just for testing reasons):

```
#iteration one:
def enter(request):
    res = make_password('admin')
    return HttpResponse(res)
```

So, when I go to `enter` page, I see this stuff:

```
pbkdf2_sha256$15000$fmX24ZPCKBdA$fvpfYMacxOi44QFDeLLfRRUN85RweMJTfxxoC+YS2XE=
```

Let's suppose that I store this output in a text file (again for testing reasons) `passwords.txt` in a form:

```
1    pbkdf2_sha256$15000$fmX24ZPCKBdA$fvpfYMacxOi44QFDeLLfRRUN85RweMJTfxxoC+YS2XE= 
2    ....hash for another user
```

On the second iteration I want to check my password (let it be stored in GET['pass'] in request variable), but do not know how:

```
def login(request):
    # How to use check_password here to check against data stored in
    # passwords.txt
    # it should either output False
    # or an id, like 1 in our test case for password 'admin'.
```

And I want to stress it again, that I want to use it manually, just in order to understand the logic behind these functions. So, I do not want to let `Django` do it for me at this moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the [`django.contrib.auth.hashers.check_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.check_password), and pass it both the unencrypted password and the encrypted string, and it returns `True` if they match, `False` if not.

Thus

```
encrypted = 'pbkdf2_sha256$15000$fmX24...'

if check_password(request.POST['pass'], encrypted):
    print("Login successful")
```

---

Note that you *don't* ever want to submit passwords using **`GET`** method, because with `GET` the passwords will be stored in logs and browser history and whatever indefinitely.

Comment: for the 2.1 version https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.check_password

Comment: @user3821178 you could write an answer